# How to install SQLAlchemy on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, linux, sqlalchemy

I want to install Python and SQLAlchemy on Ubuntu. This is my command:

```
sudo easy_install sqlalchemy
```

But it has failed, what should I do?

Comment: You should include the error...

Comment: I've never heard of any such command.

Comment: Debian and Ubuntu has already packaged sqlalchemt
sudo apt-get install python-sqlalchemy

for python 3:
sudo apt-get install python3-sqlalchemy

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Aha,sir,I can help you.
First step,you should intall the MySql,like these:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
sudo apt-get install mysql-client
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient15-dev
```

Second step,install the python-mysqldb:

```
sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb
```

Third step,install the easy_install:

```
sudo wget http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/ez_setup.py
sudo python ez_setup.py
```

Forth step,install the MySQL-Python:

```
sudo easy_install MySQL-Python
```

Finally,sqlalchemy:

```
sudo easy_install SQLAlchemy
```

Comment: I use the command "sudo su" first,and then it show that I have not the competencec,why?

Comment: Take it easy sir,you should not use the root,use you own account and then flow my step to do it.

Comment: tried this approach, but failed on the second step with error:
`    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'`

Answer (score 7):

I installed it using `pip`. After installing `mysql-server, mysql-client and libmysqlclient15-dev` and I ran following commands to install it.

```
pip install MySql-Python
pip install SQLAlchemy
```

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo pip install flask-sqlalchemy
```

This installs the SQLAlchemy package for Flask.